# The output is showing error when I convert xml into java object using JAXBException

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, jaxb

In src/main/java, I have POJO classes and in src/test/resource I have XML file. I'm writing a Junit test case where I have to parse the XML file into POJOs using JAXBException and then I have to check whether the variables are null or not.

I created a test class and added the asseertNotNull statement but after running the code as "Junit test" I'm getting some errors.

Java Class :-

```
package com.examples.demo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "book")

// Defining order
@XmlType(propOrder = { "author", "name", "publisher", "isbn" })
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    private String isbn;

    // Changing to title
    @XmlElement(name = "title")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "AuthorName")
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "publisher")
    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "isbn")
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Book{");
        sb.append("name='").append(name).append('\'');
        sb.append(", author='").append(author).append('\'');
        sb.append(", publisher='").append(publisher).append('\'');
        sb.append(", isbn='").append(isbn).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Test Class :-

```
package com.examples.demo;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

public class BookTest {

    private static final String BOOKSTORE_XML = "src/test/resources/bookstore.xml";

    @Test
    public void oneDemo() throws JAXBException, IOException, jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookStore.class);
        BookStore bookStore = (BookStore) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(BOOKSTORE_XML));

        String name = bookStore.getName();
    assertNotNull(name);

    }

}
```

XML file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:bookStore xmlns:ns2="com.zetcode">
    <bookList>
        <book AuthorName="Neil Strauss">
            <title>The Game</title>
            <publisher>Harpercollins</publisher>
            <isbn>978-0060554736</isbn>
        </book>
        <book AuthorName="Charlotte Roche">
            <title>Feuchtgebiete</title>
            <publisher>Dumont Buchverlag</publisher>
            <isbn>978-3832180577</isbn>
        </book>
    </bookList>
    <location>Livres belles</location>
    <name>Fraport Bookstore</name>
</ns2:bookStore>
```

[image: errors]

How to solve this? please help me

Comment: You never read from the file. Your code attempts to parse the file name as xml.

Comment: Also: Please post you code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Please include also the xml you are using for test.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the xml you are using for tests (I omitted non significative tags from code, up to you integrate them):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:bookStore xmlns:ns2="com.zetcode">
    <bookList>
        <book AuthorName="Neil Strauss">
            <title>The Game</title>
            <publisher>Harpercollins</publisher>
            <isbn>978-0060554736</isbn>
        </book>
        <book AuthorName="Charlotte Roche">
            <title>Feuchtgebiete</title>
            <publisher>Dumont Buchverlag</publisher>
            <isbn>978-3832180577</isbn>
        </book>
    </bookList>
    <location>Livres belles</location>
    <name>Fraport Bookstore</name>
</ns2:bookStore>
```

The first problem is about the presence of `<ns2:bookStore xmlns:ns2="com.zetcode">` tag, you have to define a `BookStore`wrapper class matching the `<bookStore>` tag to wrap the `<bookList>` tag using the [`XmlRootElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html) annotation:

```
@Data //<--lombok annotation
@XmlRootElement(name="bookStore", namespace = "com.zetcode")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) //<-- used for permit access to fields
public class BookStore {

    public BookList bookList;
}
```

You have to repeat the same process for the `bookList` tag being aware it contains a list of books with the help of the [`XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) annotation which specifies every book is an element of the list:

```
@Data 
@XmlRootElement(name="bookList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BookList {

    @XmlElement(name = "book")
    private List<Book> books;   
}

@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"author", "name", "publisher", "isbn"})
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    private String isbn;
}
```

Then you can verify that everything is ok unmarshalling and marshalling the xml, printing it to the stdout :

```
public class JaxbMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        File xml = new File("msg.xml");
        //unmarshalling the xml
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookStore.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        BookStore bookStore = (BookStore) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        //marshalling the xml to the stdout
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        //ok it prints the same xml
        marshaller.marshal(bookStore, System.out);
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error like this "Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 8 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There are two properties named "author" "
Even after making only one author.

Comment: @SGP, I added pom for clarity, the code works without problems on my side.